# Why Mongoose do not recommend passing user-defined objects as query filters?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the [mongoose doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strictQuery), they say they don't recommend passing user-defined objects as query filters. Why?

```
// Don't do this!
const docs = await MyModel.find(req.query);

// Do this instead:
const docs = await MyModel.find({ name: req.query.name, age: req.query.age }).setOptions({ sanitizeFilter: true });
```

I understand the reason of using `setOptions({sanitizeFilter: true });`

But since Mongoose wiil stipe out the property which is not in schema when `strictQuery` option is `true`. Why do we still need to use `find({ name: req.query.name, age: req.query.age })` instead of `find(req.query)`?